# spring batch, Itemwriterlistener is not registered and therefore not invoked, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-batch

I am trying to add a steplistener (ItemwriterListener) to my annotation batch configuration, no errors all, but it will not be invoked why?? It works in old xml configuration style, but not when using annotations.
code below. reader and processor are left out.

```
    @ImportResource({ "classpath*:transform-delegator-job.xml", "classpath:config/context.xml" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTransformDelegatorJobApplication {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private static final List<String> OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_LIST = null;
    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING = null;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Record> fileItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['tews.customer.url']}") String url, @Value("#{jobParameters['tews.customer.user']}") String user,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['tews.customer.pwd']}") String pwd) {
    FileItemWriter writer = new FileItemWriter();
    TewsClient client = TewsClientFactory.getInstance(user, pwd, url);
    writer.setTewsClient(client);
    writer.setHrObjectDao(hrObjectDao(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING));

    return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.delimitter']}") String delimitter, @Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.names']}") String filePath,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.encoding']}") String encoding) throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet>();

    PathResource pathResources = new PathResource(Paths.get(filePath));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pathResources.getInputStream());
    String names = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(names.split(delimitter));
    delimitedLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(delimitter);
    DefaultLineMapper<FieldSet> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<FieldSet>();
    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PassThroughFieldSetMapper());
    reader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setEncoding(encoding);
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<FieldSet, Record> csvFeedValidateProcessor(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.imeconfig.path']}") String imeConfigPath) {

    FieldCollectionConfiguration fieldCollectionConfiguration = null;
    try {
        XMLUnmarshaller<FieldcollectionType> unmarshaller = new XMLUnmarshaller<FieldcollectionType>();
        fieldCollectionConfiguration = fieldCollectionBeanToModelTransform().transform(unmarshaller.unmarshallByFile(FieldcollectionType.class, new File(imeConfigPath)));
    } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CsvFeedTransformProcessor csvFeedTransformProcessor = new CsvFeedTransformProcessor();
    csvFeedTransformProcessor.setFieldCollectionConfiguration(fieldCollectionConfiguration);
    return csvFeedTransformProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public HRObjectDao hrObjectDao(@Value("#{jobParameters['ldap.customer.url']}") String url, @Value("#{jobParameters['ldap.customer.user']}") String user,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['ldap.customer.pwd']}") String pwd, @Value("#{jobParameters['ldap.customer.bcontext']}") String bcontext) {

    return new HRObjectDaoImpl(bcontext, url, user, pwd);
    }

    @Bean
    public Transform<FieldcollectionType, FieldCollectionConfiguration> fieldCollectionBeanToModelTransform() {
    return new FieldCollectionBeanToModelTransform();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourceItemReader<FieldSet> multiResourceReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.paths'].split(',')}") List<String> filePathList) throws Exception {
    MultiResourceItemReader<FieldSet> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<FieldSet>();
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING));
    PathResource[] pathResources = new PathResource[filePathList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < filePathList.size(); i++) {
        pathResources[i] = new PathResource(Paths.get(filePathList.get(i)));
    }
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(pathResources);

    return multiResourceItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobParametersIncrementer jobParametersIncrementer() {
    return new RunIdIncrementer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilders.get("feedfiletransformer-delegate-job").listener(feedJobExecutionListener()).start(step1()).incrementer(jobParametersIncrementer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {

    return stepBuilders.get("step1").listener(fileItemWriteListener(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING)).<FieldSet, Record>chunk(1)
        .reader(multiResourceReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_LIST)).processor(csvFeedValidateProcessor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING))
        .writer(fileItemWriter(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_STRING)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FeedFileHandler feedFileHandler() {
    return new FeedFileHandlerImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriteListener<Path> fileItemWriteListener(@Value("#{jobParameters['feeddumpDirPath']}") String feeddumpDirPath,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['processedOkDirPath']}") String processedOkDirPath, @Value("#{jobParameters['processedFailedDirPath']}") String processedFailedDirPath) {

    FileItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener = new FileItemWriteListener();
    fileItemWriteListener.setFeedProcessedFailedDirectory(processedFailedDirPath);
    fileItemWriteListener.setFeedProcessedOkDirectory(processedOkDirPath);
    fileItemWriteListener.setFeeddumpDirPath(feeddumpDirPath);
    fileItemWriteListener.setFeedFileHandler(feedFileHandler());
    fileItemWriteListener.setRetryLimit(0);

    return fileItemWriteListener;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener feedJobExecutionListener() {
    return new FeedJobExecutionListener();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTransformDelegatorJobApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add `@EnableBatchProcessing`?

Comment: Well, I had to avoid this annotation in general, everything gets errorprone and my job cant start. My job is working fine (reader, processor, writer, jobexecutionlistener) without. It is just this itemwriterlistener that will not be called :( should I post all code in this config class?

Comment: yeah more of your config would help. Do you get any errors with more of the auto configuration?

Comment: all code in class just submitted. there are two config files. context.xml only related to spring's internal configuration and the other containing a scheduler. I can paste them too

Comment: yes, a typo. I have to clean it up afterwards

Comment: The jobexecutionlistener is working fine, so its kinda wierd that step listeners are left out

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it's been my experience that the best way to handle Spring java configuration is to return the explicit type on the `@Bean` method and inject the interface where needed.  The reason for this is that the `@Bean` method signature serves as providing the type to the BeanDefinition.  So if you return an interface, you may be hiding details that the framework needs while gaining virtually no benefits.  So in your example, I'd change

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener(@Value("#{jobParameters['feeddumpDirPath']}") String feeddumpDirPath, @Value("#{jobParameters['processedOkDirPath']}") String processedOkDirPath,
    @Value("#{jobParameters['processedFailedDirPath']}") String processedFailedDirPath) {
```

To

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FileItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener(@Value("#{jobParameters['feeddumpDirPath']}") String feeddumpDirPath, @Value("#{jobParameters['processedOkDirPath']}") String processedOkDirPath,
    @Value("#{jobParameters['processedFailedDirPath']}") String processedFailedDirPath) {
```

Comment: Yes, the signature did not match because I had borrowed it from another job, thats why it could not recognize. Thx for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of "trial and error", I found the reason, not easy to see.

```
    @Bean
@StepScope
public ItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener(@Value("#{jobParameters['feeddumpDirPath']}") String feeddumpDirPath, @Value("#{jobParameters['processedOkDirPath']}") String processedOkDirPath,
    @Value("#{jobParameters['processedFailedDirPath']}") String processedFailedDirPath) {

FileItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener = new FileItemWriteListener();
fileItemWriteListener.setFeedProcessedFailedDirectory(processedFailedDirPath);
fileItemWriteListener.setFeedProcessedOkDirectory(processedOkDirPath);
fileItemWriteListener.setFeeddumpDirPath(feeddumpDirPath);
fileItemWriteListener.setFeedFileHandler(feedFileHandler());
fileItemWriteListener.setRetryLimit(0);

return fileItemWriteListener;
}


[public ItemWriteListener fileItemWriteListener]

was set like this before 
 public ItemWriter<Record> fileItemWriter.


so only works without the type parameter
```

Comment: should be [ItemWriter] instead of ItemWriter<Record>. :)